# Apache Airflow UI shows DAG files from ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages rather than from the configured dag folder

Tags: airflow

I am new with Apache Airflow. I have created a DAG file to trigger Apache Ni-FI pipelines and python scripts.

In my airflow.cfg file `dags_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags`.

`airflow config get-value core DAGS_FOLDER` command gives `/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags`.

However, `airflow dags list` command shows **only** DAGS contained in the folder `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/example_dags`

and Airflow UI shows **only** the DAGS that are listed in `airflow dags list`.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can change this and make so that also Airflow UI reads from `/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags`?

I have run `airflow db init` and it did not help.

I am running Airflow 2.6.2 on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1. I have used the Airflow installation from PyPI.

Thanks,

Bernardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Set the variable `load_examples` in airflow.cfg to `False`.